# Navigation drawer below TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

- I am using `Jetpack Compose` for developing one app which contains multiple screens and we can navigate to them using `Navigation Drawer`.
- How can I put my navigation drawer below **`TopAppBar`** ( `or Toolbar`). Below is the gif for the issue:

[image: List item]

Below is the composable function for my screen:

```
fun Home(navController: NavHostController) {
    
        val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Text(
                            buildAnnotatedString {
                                append("Hello World")
                                pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium, fontSize = 12.sp))
                                append("\nhelloworld@gmail.com")
                                pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Light, fontSize = 10.sp))
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Menu,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            },
            drawerContent = {},
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            content = {
                HomeScreenContent(scaffoldState, navController)
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                    text = { Text(text = "Compose") },
                    onClick = { navController.navigate("CreateMsg") },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Create,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.White,
                        )
                    },
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it under your TopAppbar put TopAppbar and Scaffold inside a column as

```
Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
  TopAppbar()
  Scaffold()
}
```

If you want your NavigationDrawer below TopAppbar put them inside a Box with

```
Box(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
  Scaffold()
  TopAppbar()

}
```

And give your HomeContent topPadding as big as your TopAAppbar's height.

First one

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            title = {
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        append("Hello World")
                        pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium, fontSize = 12.sp))
                        append("\nhelloworld@gmail.com")
                        pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Light, fontSize = 10.sp))
                    }
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                    }
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Menu,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            }
        )

        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            drawerContent = {},
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            content = {
                HomeScreenContent(scaffoldState)
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                    text = { Text(text = "Compose") },
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Create,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.White,
                        )
                    },
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreenContent(scaffoldState: ScaffoldState) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {

        Text("HOME CONTENT", fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

Second one

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            drawerContent = {},
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            content = {
                HomeScreenContent(scaffoldState, 56.dp)
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                    text = { Text(text = "Compose") },
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Create,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.White,
                        )
                    },
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                )
            }
        )

        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            title = {
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        append("Hello World")
                        pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium, fontSize = 12.sp))
                        append("\nhelloworld@gmail.com")
                        pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Light, fontSize = 10.sp))
                    }
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                    }
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Menu,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            }
        )

    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreenContent(scaffoldState: ScaffoldState, topPadding:Dp) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top= topPadding)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {

        Text("HOME CONTENT", fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

56.dp is default size for `TopAppBar` on my device. If you have custom height you need to get it via Modifier.onSizeChanged{} Modifier that set to `TopAppBar`.

Comment: I am using `1st solution` and that is working for me. Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: Also can you tell me something about scrolling TopAppBar while we scroll through the list?

Comment: If you need to have Collapsed TopAppbar you should either check Material3 TopAppbars or nested scrolling.

Comment: No just the normal scroll like that we were doing in xml using : `app:layout_behaviour`.

Comment: It's not avaiable for Compose TopAppbar but Material Design3 TopAppbars support it i guess.